# CakePHP adding image to echo $this->Html->link

Tags: image, cakephp, cakephp-2.8

Hi I have tried various things but not sure if I am trying to over complicate things. Quite simply I want to add a small image country flag for the word 'Spanish' and 'English' and have an 'Alt' tag with those words instead. The following works fine with just text and as is but it would be cool to have the image either to replace or sit side by side with the word. Any help available?

```
    echo $this->Html->link('Spanish', array('controller'=>'settings', 'action'=>'lang', 'spa'),
        array('rel'=>'nofollow'));
}

else {
    echo $this->Html->link('English', array('controller'=>'settings', 'action'=>'lang', 'eng'),
        array('rel'=>'nofollow'));
}
```

Comment: I should add the html out put for English is like this at the moment: <a href="/lang/eng" rel="nofollow">English</a> </div>

Comment: please tag the question accordingly to you exact cakephp version

Comment: Thank you, CakePHP 2.8

Answer (score 1):

You can either output just a linked image using the `image` method with a `url` attribute:-

```
<?php

echo $this->Html->image(
    'spain.jpg', 
    array(
        'alt' => 'Spanish',
        'url' => array('controller' => 'settings', 'action' => 'lang', 'spa')
    )
);
```

Or you can include an image with a text link by combining the normal CakePHP `link` method and the `image` method:-

```
<?php

echo $this->Html->link(
    h('Spanish') . $this->Html->image('spain.jpg', array('alt' => 'Spanish')),
    array('controller' => 'settings', 'action' => 'lang', 'spa'),
    array('escape' => false, 'rel' => 'nofollow')
);
```

With the `link` method you need to remember to prevent Cake from escaping the `img` tag using `'escape' => false`. If you disable escaping like this it is work remembering to escape any user provided text by using the `h()` method to prevent any HTML injection (I've shown this in my example wrapping the word 'Spanish' but this is only necessary if this is coming from a variable).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using cake2 see [**this**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::image) link to the cookbook

```
echo $this->Html->image("spain.jpg", array(
    "alt" => "Spanish language",
    'url' => array('controller' => 'settings', 'action' => 'lang', 'spa')
));
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. It broke the page. I am using version 2.8. I just want the code I put up to give this output:<a href="/lang/spa" rel="nofollow">Spanish<img src="/img/spain.jpg" class="photo" alt="Spanish"/></a>

Comment: please explain: do you want the image to be a link, or do you simply want the image to be right after the link but not clickable?

Comment: Sorry making mistakes...nervous!

Comment: I would like the image to be clickable. With the alt attribute word to say Spanish

Comment: If it is easier just to put the image next to the link that would help me. Thanks

Comment: Hello arillia, I tried your code again and it works. Don't know why it didn't the first time. :)